Why can my Cloud Build only run 5 or 6 builds at once?
The way I'm using Cloud Build makes it so that I can have several builds running at once. When I try running more than around 5 or 6 builds, however, other builds are queued and are not run until the previous 5 or 6 builds complete. How can I raise the number of concurrent builds that my Cloud Build can run?
A little more information:

I'm not using a private worker pool currently.
I see no quotas being hit for cloudbuild.googleapis.com.
My "Concurrent builds" quota is set to 10 max, but has 0% usage even when I have several builds running at once.


Can you detail what are you doing in your Cloud Build, especially if you deploy Cloud Functions or App Engine?

My Cloud Build is currently set up to deploy docker images to artifact registry, and to deploy those to Cloud Run. I also have my Cloud Build pipelines set up to trigger each other with PubSub (so my artifact registry push will trigger a deploy-to-dev pipeline after it completes). Builds can last around 3 minutes, usually, but I plan on having a lot of builds going on at once at some point. I'd like to have at least 10 concurrent builds.

Review your Cloud Build quotas: https://console.cloud.google.com/iam-admin/quotas?service=cloudbuild.googleapis.com What type of account do you have (free trial, paid)?

I see no quotas being hit for cloudbuild.googleapis.com. There are also no quotas being hit for anything else. I'm using a paid account.

Google Gemini Pro had this to say about why I'm having this issue:
"When not using a private worker pool, you share resources with other Cloud Build users. This shared pool has inherent limitations on the number of concurrent builds it can handle, which might be causing the queuing you're experiencing."
So it looks like the quota isn't on my GCP project, but on Cloud Build's public shared worker pool. So if I want more builds at once, I'll probably have to make a private worker pool.
